# Making a generic type a variable

Tags: c#, generics

```
var type = data.ClientBaseObject.GetType();
var newClientObject = GetDataContextedObject(type, data.ClientBaseObject);


private object GetDataContextedObject(Type type, object jobObject)
    {
        switch (type.Name.ToUpper())
        {
            case "JOBNUMBER":
                {
                    return GetObjectFromDataContext<JobNumber>(jobObject);
                }
            case "NA_HEADER":
                {
                    return GetObjectFromDataContext<NA_Header>(jobObject);
                }
        }
        return null;
    }

        private  object GetObjectFromDataContext<T>(object jobObject) where T: class, IJobID
        {
            var newObject = jobObject as T;
            return _dc.GetTable<T>().FirstOrDefault(j => j.JobID == newObject.JobID);
        }
```

In the above code, I am wondering if there is a way I can make the `GetObjectFromDataContext` into `GetObjectFromDataContext<type>`, instead of having to get the type.Name for each class and creating a case for each one.  Can this be done?

Let me know if the question is not clear.

Comment: How do you plan to call this method? If you show us some context it may help.

Comment: updated the code for more clarification

Comment: You really should consider reviewing your design. Can you post the requirement for this case?

Answer (score 0):

Do all of the allowable types implement a common interface?  If so, then yes; change `GetObjectFromDataContext` to accept the base type as a generic argument.

However, a generic argument must be determined at compile time.  Otherwise how would the feature provide type safety?  You may as well just be passing everything around as an `object` at that point.

EDIT: Per your update.

I you *must* be able to pass in a `Type` parameter at runtime, then no, you can't do what you want. Since this is all occurring at runtime you will have to selectively call the generic version.  You cannot use [the overload of `GetTable` that takes a `Type` argument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310460.aspx) for the same reason; you'll need a cast as it returns an `ITable`.

Do you really need to do this dynamically using a `Type` parameter?

Comment: Don't have to do it that way, but I'm just trying to lessen the blow of maintenance.  Don't wanna have to add an extra case every time a new class is added

Comment: Arguably, if you like pain, you could rewrite as a genetic call and at runtime ascertain the right method to invoke via MakeGenericMethod...

Comment: @DJBurb If the class holding this method were called `Foo` and the method signature `public void Bar<T>()`, you could find the right method for any `Type t` with something like `typeof(Foo).GetMethod("Bar").MakeGenericMethod(t)` - I MUST STRESS THIS IS A REFLECTION CALL and probably slower than you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

You can write it this way:

```
private object GetDataContextedObject<T>(object jobObject)
{
    return GetObjectFromDataContext<T>(jobObject);
}
```

Comment: Maybe.  It depends upon how `T` is used within the method.

Comment: I need to clarify my question I think.  I don't know which class I am going to get.  I'll add more code

Comment: Sure. For simple cases, where you only want to get datasets from EF, this should do the work, but I can't recommend its use for all cases.

Comment: I added more code for clarification.  I am calling a GetType() to get the type

Comment: If this worked then the wrapper would be useless.  It won't work however due to this part: `.FirstOrDefault(j => j.JobID == newObject.JobID);`